# Finding the angle between a prism's edge and one of its faces.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I’m having difficulty on how to start off the following question:

[image]

I know that forming a right-angled triangle AMJ with M as the midpoint of GH could be a good starting point, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Any ideas on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For context, is this a problem within synthetic geometry or analytic geometry? In the latter I’d suggest use of coordinates and vector analysis, though the latter can be dispensed with. By contrast, if one is avoiding coordinates then the approach will likely be different.

Comment: HINT. You can find lengths of sides and height of triangle $CDE$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's find $x$. $\triangle CDE$ is isosceles with legs $8$ and base angle $\pi \over 6$. Thus, $x=8\sin \frac{\pi}{3}=4\sqrt 3$.

Let $M$ be midpoint of $GH$. We have that $JM$ is perpendicular to the base thus $\angle JAM$ will be the required angle.

We also have that $AM^2=x^2+12^2, JM=x+\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}$. Can you finish?

Comment: This is very well done and makes a lot of sense.